# jQuery object: summing all instances of value A where value B is duplicate

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, knockout.js

I have this object of VAT values:

```
[
{
 "code": "2",
 "rate": "17.5%",
 "net": 0
},
{
 "code": "2",
 "rate": "17.5%",
 "net": 0
},
{
 "code": "1",
 "rate": "Zero Rated",
 "net": 0
},
{
 "code": "1",
 "rate": "Zero Rated",
 "net": 0
},
{
 "code": "4",
 "rate": "20%",
 "net": 304.7
},
{
 "code": "1",
 "rate": "Zero Rated",
 "net": 0
},
{
 "code": "4",
 "rate": "20%",
 "net": 1200.24
},
{
 "code": "4",
 "rate": "20%",
 "net": 5201.04
},
{
 "code": "4",
 "rate": "20%",
 "net": 1258.82
},
{
 "code": "4",
 "rate": "20%",
 "net": 629.41
},
{
 "code": "4",
 "rate": "20%",
 "net": 629.41
}
]
```

What I want to do is to display all separate codes with their respective values summed up, i.e. I want to add up all Net values where VAT Code is 1 and display it (Code, Rate and total Net), then separately display them where VAT Code is 2, etc.

I have tried using $.each, creating a new object and comparing the two and either adding values or creating a new instance where the codes are equal but it got messy and confusing:

```
var vatAnalysisItem = [];

$.each(self.vat(), function(index) {
  $.each(self.vat()[index], function(key1, value1) {
    if(key1 == "code") {
      if(vatAnalysisItem.length === 0) {
        vatAnalysisItem.push({code: self.vat().code, rate: self.vat().rate, net: self.vat().net});
      }
      else {
        $.each(vatAnalysisItem, function(key2, value2) {
          if(key2 == "code")
            if(value in vatAnalysisItem) {
              vatAnalysisItem[net] += self.vat().net;
            }
            else {
              vatAnalysisItem.push({code: self.vat()[code], rate: self.vat().rate, net: self.vat().net});
            }
        });
      }
    }
  });
});
```

. I am not sure how to go about doing this. I will use Knockout JS to display the complete values in the View.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: share what you have tried

Comment: @ArunPJohny - edited the post. As I said, it started to look very messy and as it wasn't doing what I needed it to whatsoever, I realised it was probably not the way to do it

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7Lzzute9/1/ ?

Comment: try http://underscorejs.org/  underscore.js its meant for such collection tasks.

Comment: @ArunPJohny - thank you very much, it works like a charm! Really appreciate it :)

Comment: @cyril - thanks, I will check out the library to see if it might help in future work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sort order is likely wrong, adjust to taste.

```js
var vm = {
  data: ko.observableArray([]),
  cumulativeData: ko.pureComputed(function() {
    var result = {};
    vm.data().forEach(function(datum) {
      var cumul = result[datum.code];
      if (!cumul) {
        result[datum.code] = cumul = {
          code: datum.code,
          rate: datum.rate,
          net: 0
        };
      }
      cumul.net += datum.net;
    });
    return Object.keys(result).sort().map(function(code) { return result[code]; });
  })
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);

var newData = [{"code":"2","rate":"17.5%","net":0},{"code":"2","rate":"17.5%","net":0},{"code":"1","rate":"Zero Rated","net":0},{"code":"1","rate":"Zero Rated","net":0},{"code":"4","rate":"20%","net":304.7},{"code":"1","rate":"Zero Rated","net":0},{"code":"4","rate":"20%","net":1200.24},{"code":"4","rate":"20%","net":5201.04},{"code":"4","rate":"20%","net":1258.82},{"code":"4","rate":"20%","net":629.41},{"code":"4","rate":"20%","net":629.41}];
vm.data(newData);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<table data-bind="foreach: cumulativeData">
  <tr>
    <td data-bind="text: code"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: rate"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: net"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: brilliant, thank you for taking KO into account, works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple loop with a temp object like

```js
var items = [{
  "code": "2",
  "rate": "17.5%",
  "net": 0
}, {
  "code": "2",
  "rate": "17.5%",
  "net": 0
}, {
  "code": "1",
  "rate": "Zero Rated",
  "net": 0
}, {
  "code": "1",
  "rate": "Zero Rated",
  "net": 0
}, {
  "code": "4",
  "rate": "20%",
  "net": 304.7
}, {
  "code": "1",
  "rate": "Zero Rated",
  "net": 0
}, {
  "code": "4",
  "rate": "20%",
  "net": 1200.24
}, {
  "code": "4",
  "rate": "20%",
  "net": 5201.04
}, {
  "code": "4",
  "rate": "20%",
  "net": 1258.82
}, {
  "code": "4",
  "rate": "20%",
  "net": 629.41
}, {
  "code": "4",
  "rate": "20%",
  "net": 629.41
}];

var result = [],
  tmp = {};
$.each(items, function(i, item) {
  if (!tmp[item.code]) {
    tmp[item.code] = {
      "code": item.code,
      "rate": item.rate,
      "net": 0
    };
    result.push(tmp[item.code]);
  }
  console.log(tmp[item.code])
  tmp[item.code].net += item.net;
});

output.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result, null, 2)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the codes as keys in a new object which would make it easy to grab the information you need:

```
var out = arr.reduce(function (p, c) {
  var key = c.code;
    if (!p[key]) p[key] = { rate: c.rate, net: 0}
    p[key].net += c.net;
    return p;
}, {});

out['4'].net // 9223.619999999999
```

**OUTPUT**

```
{
    "1": {
        "rate": "Zero Rated",
        "net": 0
    },
    "2": {
        "rate": "17.5%",
        "net": 0
    },
    "4": {
        "rate": "20%",
        "net": 9223.619999999999
    }
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/n2qjnxm3/)